# how to solve nested exception is: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host. in jmeter while working on EC2 instance

Tags: jmeter

I want to do remote/distributed testing on jmeter for which i am using 3 EC2 instances. 1 is master and 2 are slave machines.

i have done all the settings in jmeter.properties file:
i set these properties in all machines:

```
Remote_Hosts=ip_address1, ip_address
client.rmi.localport=50000 
server.rmi.localport=4000
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true 
server-port=8099  
server.rmi.port=8099
```

I am using 3 EC2 instances for 3 different locations.

and when i am trying to run script its giving error to me
[image]

can anyone help me what is the issue here and how can i fix it.
is there anything which i am missing in jmeter config?

Answer (score 0):

As per [NoRouteToHost](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html) exception description

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

1. Use [public IP instead of private IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html)
2. Make sure that the relevant RMI ports are open in operating system [firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) and [AWS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)
3. Check if you're using [IPv4 or IPv6 addresses](https://kinsta.com/blog/ipv4-vs-ipv6/) and stick to one stack everywhere
4. `server properties need to be set on Master side only,` client` properties need to be set on Slaves

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: 1.  i am using public ip
2. AWS Security groups are fine. 
3. using IPV4.
4. JMeter settings. here do you mean that client.rmi.localport=50000  should be on slave and  server.rmi.localport=4000 and other sever properties should be on master side?

Comment: 1. You're lying at my face as I clearly see a local class A subnet address, addresses from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 are reserved for private networks and are not routable for global Internet. 2, 3 and 4 I suspect the same. I would recommend using scripts like [jmeter-ec2](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) or services like [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/solutions/jmeter) if you have problems with configuring 2 properties.